# Wordpress wpdb->delete issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to delete a record from the database programmatically. When I have it hardcoded like this it does delete a record from the database:

```
$wpdb->delete( $table_name, array( 'user_id' => 1, 'timeMin' => 10), array('%d', '%d') );
```

However, when I try to do it in a dynamic manner with variables, it doesn't work. I even tried casting the variables to `int` to make sure they are they right type.

```
$id = (int) wp_get_current_user()->ID;
$time = (int) $_POST['umjp_time'];

$wpdb->delete( $table_name, array( 'user_id' => $id, 'timeMin' => $time), array('%d','%d'));
```

Why doesn't the dynamic code using variables work and how do I fix this?

Comment: why not just use `$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare())`?

Comment: I'll try, I thought this was the recommended way but it's not working

Comment: with Wordpress I find that their standards/best practices are to avoid haha

Comment: First: **do use** `$wpdb->delete`.  It handles a lot of the `prepare`, etc. behind the scenes.  Second: what do you get when you `var_dump($id)`? or `var_dump($time)`?  The problem is _almost certainly_ related to the values in those variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how I would recommend doing it:

```
function vendor_module_remove_dealer($data)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'. $wpdb->prefix .'my_table` WHERE `primary_id` = %d;';

    try {
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($sql, array($data['primary-id'])));

        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 'Error! '. $wpdb->last_error;
    }
}
```

this will prevent SQL Injection and delete your record safely, if it fails an error msg will be returned :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried like this and it's working for me.

```
global $wpdb;

$id = (int) wp_get_current_user()->ID;
$time = (int) '4';
$table_name = 'testtable';
$wpdb->show_errors(); 
$wpdb->delete( $table_name, array( 'user_id' => $id, 'timeMin' => $time), array('%d','%d'));
$wpdb->print_error();
```

What errors you are getting please can you explain?
You can print errors by using show_errors() and print_error() methods.

Comment: This is probably the most correct solution.  Those using DELETE FROM will work, but that isn't how wpdb is intended to work.  A little explanation would work - the critical piece being the user of array('%d') which converts the integer appropriately.

Answer (score -2):

Please use below code i think it will work.

```
global $wpdb;

$id = (int) wp_get_current_user()->ID;
$time = (int) $_POST['umjp_time'];

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_name';
if (!empty($id)) 
{

  $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE user_id IN($id)"));

}
```

Comment: this is open to SQL Injection :) should use the `prepare` method

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.  Why does this work, where OP's code doesn't?  Further, this is _wide open_ to SQL injection.  Don't post answers that are open to this sort of security attack.

Comment: sorry for missing $wpdb->prepare but now i had added.

Comment: @raju_eww it's still open to SQL injection :)

Comment: You need to look into how to use `$wpdb->prepare`.  It's not being used properly in your code.